# Discussion Board - add a column with an icon that when clicked opens up the Flat/Threaded View?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, discussion-board

Title says it all.  I'd like to add an icon to each list item row that when clicked, performs the same function as the "Title (linked to item with edit menu)" i.e. it opens up the Flat or Threaded view for that subject.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use CSS on existing Title-columns, like this:

```
.ms-vb-title .ms-vb a {
  background-image: url(http://goo.gl/A444j);
  background-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
}
```

If you use jQuery and want to instantly show the effect, run this:

```
$('.ms-vb-title .ms-vb a').css({
  backgroundImage: 'url(http://goo.gl/A444j)',
  backgroundSize: 16,
  backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
  paddingLeft: 20
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I generally focus on the server-side of things and overlook client-side solutions.  I will see if I can make this approach work.

Comment: This way you attach this icon to all hyperlinks in the view body, not specifically to one new or existing column. And there's no control of what the link shall open.